# Convert TuxGuitar Drum Track to Addictive Drums

Tags: wine, music, jack, midi, tuxguitar

The scenario:

- Use TuxGuitar in Ubuntu 12.04 to Compose a Guitar Track and a Drum (Percussion) Track
- Practice song on Guitar while listening to TuxGuitar play the track(s) through the Gervill MIDI Port
- Eventually place the Drum track on Solo and use Jack+Wine+vsthost to listen to the Drum track through the Addictive Drums 1.0.0 (VSTi)
- Play guitar along with the drum track as it is plays through Addictive Drums

The problem:

- The KeyMap for the Drum Track in TuxGuitar is different than Addictive Drums Keymap
- For example, 48 in TuxGuitar maps to a tom hit, while 48 in Addictive Drums maps to a hi-hat hit.

Acknowledgement(s):

- One could manually go through each drum track in TuxGuitar and map each note according to the Addictive Drums Keymap, but then the we have the same problem in reverse, where the drums sound good in Addictive Drums, but not in Tuxguitar.

The question:

- How to convert a Tux Guitar Drum Track Keymap to an Addictive Drums Keymap in an automated way?

Desired solution(s):

- Be able to quickly convert a Tux Guitar Drums Track Keymap to an Addictive Drums Keymap
- Be able to quickly convert back and forth between the two

Possible solution(s):

- Write a TuxGuitar plugin
- Write some kind of program (maybe using c++, java, or PHP) to do it
- I heard newer versions of Addictive Drums have a Guitar Pro Keymap built in (so theoretically it will work for TuxGuitar if this is true)

Answer (score 1):

From: http://www.xlnaudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=704

"Ok, then you can use the drum map available in the "User area/User Downloads" area! This will remap the midi from GP (which I guess is GM compatible) into the AD keymap. 
You can also drag'n'drop files from AD's beat library into Cubase to build your drum tracks, 3600 beats and fills recorded by a real drummer!"

Comment: Thanks @JefAlive, I stumbled across this before. But unfortunately this only works with a later version of AddictiveDrums, which I don't have :P